# What does "Safari (in-app) in Google Analytics refer to?"

Tags: google-analytics

Can someone please explain what "Safari (in-app)" means in Google Analytics under Audience | Technology | Browser & OS?

For the Google Analytics for our website, we suddenly started to see significant traffic from this source.

It sounds like it just means that visitors are coming to us through browsers embedded within apps (e.g. like a web viewing control) except that there doesn't seem to be reason why we should be getting such traffic and so suddenly.

We went from zero traffic from this source to almost 40% of our traffic in only two days for no apparent reason!  We haven't done anything that can explain this sudden new source of traffic (e.g. we haven't released any apps ourselves) that point back at our website.  We're hoping that, if we can find out what "in-app" actually means, we'll be able to understand this traffic.

Thank you

Comment: Is there a corresponding fall-off in one of your other `Browser & OS` entries?  Or does this seem to be mostly new traffic?

Comment: It seems to be mostly new traffic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did some tests on a separate page available only for me using IOS 8.2 and updated 1Password and Facebook App:

1. General Safari browser is reported as Safari 8.0:

   Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12D508 Safari/600.1.4
2. 1Password is reported as Safari 6.0:

   Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25
3. Facebook App is reported as Safari (in-app)

   Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12D508 [FBAN/FBIOS;FBAV/27.0.0.10.12;FBBV/8291884;FBDV/iPhone7,2;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iPhone OS;FBSV/8.2;FBSS/2; FBCR/Play;FBID/phone;FBLC/en_US;FBOP/5]

Tested on 2015.03.31 (yyyy.mm.dd)

Answer (score 6):

Visitors using built-in search box within Safari are now having their searches sent though Google SSL Search, if they use iOS 6. Searches done with Google and through Safari's search box will continue to grow, as people continue to upgrade to iOS 6 (currently for iPhone 4/4S highest version is 6.1.3, for iPhone 5 is 6.1.4). Also Google updated their user-agent parsing code and UA like this:

```
1Password
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) 1Password/4.1.2 (like Version/10B143 Mobile/6.1 Safari/8536.25)
```

will be categorised like Safari (in-app).

Read more in the articles below and do not trust Google Analytics fully.

Hope this helps!

[iOS 6 change Google traffic from Safari](http://searchengineland.com/ios-6-change-google-traffic-from-safari-135002)

[Safari (in-app) as reported by Google Analytics](http://www.jongales.com/blog/2013/02/13/safari-in-app-as-reported-by-google-analytics/)

Comment: I was having same idea - but I can 100% confirm that user agent from your reply is tagged as Safari 6 not Safari (in-app). I made some tests on a separate site where only I had an access and 1Password is not Safari (in-app) but Safari 6.

Comment: @MarcinBobowski You could add it as an answer here along with the tests. I haven't been playing with this in about an year, so it's possible Google UA parsing code to be changed along the way.

Comment: I did with a little bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As you concluded, many people think those represent traffic from iOS apps opening links not on the browser but inside the app (WebView). However, I haven't being able to find a concrete Google Documentation on that.

As for the sudden increase, it is not unusual. Just yesterday I saw how HTC Hero (#1 Device in visits) went from 25.000 visits/day to 0 in two days, and Elocity A7 A7 Internet Tablet from 0 to 30.000 visits/day at the same time. Seems, Google keeps updating its User-Agent Parsing code.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed it being reported in email tracking. Could it be Email Opens in Safari if you have set up email tracking in GA.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like people accessing your website via a home screen bookmark. "Add to Home Screen" function, rather than via the Safari browser are listed as "Safari (in-app)".

I'm looking at a GA account that only watches iPads displaying a "WebApp". It looks like those devices running 10.3.2 and higher display as "Safari (in-app)" and those below show as "Safari" only.

This would also explain the sudden jump in metrics. As users update their iOS will suddenly be listed as "Safari (in-app)".