# How to know differentiate Mobile App vs Mobile Web Browser in Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, symfony-2.3, google-analytics-filters

I use this code:

`$analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:' . $config['profileId'],
    '2005-01-01',
    'today',
    'ga:sessions',
    array(
        'dimensions' => 'ga:browser',
        'filters' => 'ga:operatingSystem==iOS;ga:browser=@in-app
    )
);`

I don't know what to put in `filters` to get all Android that uses native app and Android that uses web view.

I saw that in the list, `ga:browser` there is Safari (in-app) for iOS that seperates iOS WebView from a iOS browser. I read it from [here](https://moz.com/community/q/what-does-safari-in-app-mean-in-google-analytics-browser-traffic) and [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440581/what-does-safari-in-app-in-google-analytics-refer-to).

I need something like that from Android or better than that.